How to calculate zoom from a scale in leaflet?
I have a scale on the map in this format 1:100000, when I use a button to say the scale I want, for example 1000, instead of going to 1:1000 it goes to 1:3,859,087, when I use 100 it goes to 1: 365,931. I'm probably miscalculating the zoom from the scale, but I don't know how I could fix that.
const confirm = () => {
  if (!scaleValue.value || !props.mapObject) return;

  const lat = props.mapObject.getCenter().lat;

  const earthCircumference = 40075016.686;

  const initialResolution = earthCircumference / 256;

  const resolutionAtLat = initialResolution * Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180);

  const desiredResolution = scaleValue.value / resolutionAtLat;

  const newZoomLevel = Math.log2(1 / desiredResolution);

  console.log(`Scale value: 1:${scaleValue.value}`);
  console.log(`Calculated zoom level: ${newZoomLevel}`);  

  props.mapObject.setZoom(newZoomLevel);
  scaleDialogVisible.value = false;
}

This is how the output looks like in my console
Scale value: 1:10000
Calculated zoom level: 3.9112136716189645
Scale value: 1:100
Calculated zoom level: 10.554988990338934

I've tried changing the calculation formula, but I still can't.

You will have a better chance of solving the problem by providing a workable demo that can to be debugged, since it depends on undocumented behavior of a particular library and is unlikely to be solved on paper
